# Is there a way to make a shell become interactive in the middle of a script?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, shell

I'd like to do something like:

```
do lots of stuff to prepare a good environement
become_interactive
#wait for Ctrl-D
automatically clean up
```

Is it possible with bash? If not, do you see another way of doing the same thing?

Comment: Thanks a lot to both of you for your answers!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Structure it like this:

test.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
exec bash --rcfile environ.sh
```

environ.sh

```
cleanup() {
    echo "Cleaning up"
}
trap cleanup EXIT
echo "Initializing"
PS1='>> '
```

In action:

```
~$ ./test.sh 
Initializing
>> exit
Cleaning up
```

Answer (score 2):

You can invoke another shell in the middle of the script, but changes to e.g. environment variables would not be reflected outside of it.